# https://github.com not fully loading

Tags: ubuntu, github

When I try to open [Github](https://github.com) on Opera, Firefox and Google Chrome; It shows up like following.

[image: HERE]

I also get the following errors:

[image: HERE]

Using `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

[image]

Comment: Is the clock on your computer correct?

Comment: it is indeed correct, why tho?

Comment: Too many weird errors. Are you using a super-tight security software?

Comment: This typically happens when you have security software or are connected to a proxy.  Are you connected to an Enterprise network?

Comment: I'm a bit new to it, and also not sure. How do I check?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are connected to a proxy network (at school or some workplace).

The only way to get around this is contacting your IT department and ask them to allow github.com through the proxy.

You could also try using a VPN or Tor, but if this is against your company/organization's rules, you may get into trouble.

Try [downloading Tor here](https://www.torproject.org/) and connecting to github as long as you know it is not against your organization regulations

Comment: Alright ima try that